# Android - Google Voice Search

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to implement Google Voice Search in my app. The module is simple where I speak "Cafe" and application goes to Google Map and returns me relevant results. Is there any tutorials for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the answer is "no". In order to achieve what you want, you have to learn two things:

1. Speech to text with [Speech to text guide](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/)
2. Use [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=vi) API to retrieve the `Places` results and display it on the map.